# How to change the default listen port of apacheDS?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, apacheds

I have installed apacheDS 2.0 M17 on a centos 6.5 box. Now I want to change the default listener ports 10389 and 10636 to the standard 389 and 636 ones. For this I have changed the values in the file "**/var/lib/apacheds-2.0.0_M17/default/conf/config.ldif**" but when I start the server from init script, it doesn't start listening, but the wrapper log says wrapper jumpstarted java successfully. This happens both when running from root and apacheds user. I thought about using port redirect in iptables, but it adds dependency on iptables service. Then I thought of using "**setcap**" but I don't know whether to apply it on the wrapper program or the init script or java binary. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but it doesn't look like it was ever answered, so for posterity's sake the answer is that 'setcap' needs to be applied to the Java binary.

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

That appears to have done the trick for me, and my ApacheDS is now running on the standard service ports.